# No Internet access while connected with Cisco AnyConnect VPN client

Tags: vpn, cisco, route, static-routes

I joined a Cisco IPSEC VPN (based on Group Authentication).

I had to install the VPN using some tricks since is not working anymore on Windows 10.

The problem is that once connected in VPN internet is no working anymore.

This is my route table

```
 IPv4 Tabella route
===========================================================================
Route attive:
     Indirizzo rete             Mask          Gateway     Interfaccia Metrica
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.161     55
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    10.210.222.65    10.210.222.77     36
    10.210.222.64  255.255.255.224         On-link     10.210.222.77    291
    10.210.222.77  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.210.222.77    291
    10.210.222.95  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.210.222.77    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
    192.41.62.132  255.255.255.255    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.161    100
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.161    311
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0    10.210.222.65    10.210.222.77 942292828
    192.168.1.161  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.161    311
    192.168.1.254  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.161    100
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.161    311
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255    10.210.222.65    10.210.222.77 946224920
   192.168.212.80  255.255.255.240         On-link    192.168.212.81    271
   192.168.212.80  255.255.255.240    10.210.222.65    10.210.222.77 943865604
   192.168.212.81  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.212.81    271
   192.168.212.81  255.255.255.255    10.210.222.65    10.210.222.77 943603552
   192.168.212.95  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.212.81    271
   192.168.212.95  255.255.255.255    10.210.222.65    10.210.222.77 946487068
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    192.168.212.81    271
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.161    311
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     10.210.222.77    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    192.168.212.81    271
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.161    311
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     10.210.222.77    291
```

I tried to delete the entry:
  0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    10.210.222.65    10.210.222.77     36
since my internet working gateway is 192.168.1.254 but its still not working.

I searched anywhere but nothing was working.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Have you checked your DNS settings? Please show output for `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping google.com`.

Comment: Yes, i checked it..i don't know what to do....

Comment: Show output for `nslookup google.com`.

Comment: This is the output:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> nslookup google.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  10.210.210.10

It look like it' still using the DNS server of VPN (that i suppose i should keep for resolve name of the VPN).

Since i deleted the "route redirect" for internet with this command:
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.210.222.65

I suppose it should use as gateway this one:
      0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    192.168.1.161     55
That is from my real gatweway.

Why is not using this network DNS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have access to Internet because your default resolver is DNS provided by AnyConnect. Those DNS couldn't resolve names from Internet. According [Cisco forums](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/vpn/dns-priority/td-p/3025465) that issue and routing issue could be fixed only on server side. Sounds like you should talk with your IT team.